# Livepatch service fails with: "error checking platform, permission denied"

Tags: permissions, 18.04, canonical-livepatch

I tried installing and using the Canonical Livepatch service, but after installing the snap, I am unable to proceed with the next step:

```
sudo canonical-livepatch enable ID
```

After running this command I get the following error:

```
error executing enable: Livepatchd error: Error checking platform: open /etc/lsb-release: permission denied
```

I am running Pop!_OS 18.04 LTS with kernel version Linux pop-os 4.13.0-38-generic.

It seems like the root privileges are failing to take effect when running that command. Not sure if I'm supposed to change the permissions of lsb-release (seems like a bad idea).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pop!_OS [is not Ubuntu.](http://pop.system76.com/docs/difference-between-pop-ubuntu/) Nothing I've been able to find indicates that Canonical supports Pop!_OS via the [livepatch service.](https://www.ubuntu.com/server/livepatch) To the best of my knowledge livepatch is only supported on LTS versions of Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04. Support has also been added for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS More information on Canonical Livepatch service can be found [here.](https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/ac3aa269-DS_Canonical_Livepatch_Service_screen-AW_08.17.pdf?) Details regarding supported kernel variants can be found [in the wiki.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Livepatch)

Comment: I guess that's true. I was just hoping they were similar enough that it would work. Thanks!